# How to configure Tomcat to run an Google App Engine + GWT application on Mac OS X?

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, gwt

Does anyone know a good tutorial on this?
What Tomcat version must be used?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Tomcat to run an App Engine app (unless it doesn't make use of any App Engine specific APIs - in which case, configure it as you would for any other servlet app). You need to use the provided SDK, or the Eclipse plugin, documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing.html).