# Save Image in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, client-library

I'm currently working on a project where we should have the possibility to upload files to the Google Cloud Storage. So we created an Bucket and I added the Maven dependency to my local "normal" application:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then I started to read a local file and tried to push that to the Google Cloud Storage in a simply main:

```
try {
    final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory
        .createGcsService();

    File file = new File("/tmp/test.jpg");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("test1213","test.jpg");
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
    outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
    copy(fis, Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My `copy` method looks like this:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;

private static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
        output.close();
    }
}
```

All I get from that is this:

```
The API package 'file' or call 'Create()' was not found.
```

After searching a lot in google, reading documentations even searching in bing i found this entry: [The API package 'channel' or call 'CreateChannel()' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813668/the-api-package-channel-or-call-createchannel-was-not-found)

It says that there is no way to use the `appengine.tools -> gcs-client` without such an AppEngine App. But is there an easy way to upload files to the Google Cloud Storage without to be forced on using the AppEngine service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're not using App Engine. That's completely fine. Google Cloud Storage can work fine with App Engine, but it by no means requires it. The appengine-gcs-client package you're trying to use does require App Engine, though.

Instead, you want google-api-services-storage.

There's an example of using the GCS JSON API with Java and Maven here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples

Comment: Thanks for this example, I will have a look at it - this afternoon or next week. After trying and playing around with this json-api I will come back! +1 of for the fast help for the moment :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for my servlet APP Engine which get back data and photo, then store them to datastore and cloud storage.
Hope it help you..

```
@Override
          public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
              throws ServletException, IOException {            

            //Get GCS service
            GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();

            //Generate string for my photo
            String unique = UUID.randomUUID().toString();     

            //Open GCS File
            GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(CONSTANTES.BUCKETNAME, unique+".jpg");               

            //Set Option for that file
            GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
                    .mimeType("image/jpg")
                    .acl("public-read")
                    .build();


            //Canal to write on it
            GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);

            //For multipart support
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(); 

            //Trying to create file   
            try {


                FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);


                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        FileItemStream item = iterator.next();                      
                        InputStream stream = item.openStream();

                        if (item.isFormField()) {                       

                          String texte_recu_filtre = IOUtils.toString(stream);                       

                          if (item.getFieldName().equals("Type")){
                              Type=Integer.parseInt(texte_recu_filtre);                           
                          }else if (item.getFieldName().equals("DateHeure")){
                              DateHeure=texte_recu_filtre;
                          }else if (item.getFieldName().equals("NumPort")){
                              NumPort=texte_recu_filtre;
                          }else if (item.getFieldName().equals("CodePays")){
                              CodePays=Integer.parseInt(texte_recu_filtre);
                          }

                        } else {                    


                          byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream);

                          try {
                                //Write data from photo
                                writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));                             

                          } finally {                             

                                writeChannel.close();
                                stream.close();

                                /
                                res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);

                                res.setContentType("text/plain");
                          }        
                        }        
                  }



                Key<Utilisateur> cleUtilisateur = Key.create(Utilisateur.class, NumPort);               


                Utilisateur posteur = ofy().load().key(cleUtilisateur).now();               

                //Add to datatstore with Objectify
                Campagne photo_uploaded = new Campagne(CONSTANTES.chaineToDelete+unique+".jpg", Type, date_prise_photo, 0, cleUtilisateur, CodePays, posteur.getliste_contact());

                ofy().save().entity(photo_uploaded).now();                          


                } catch (FileUploadException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               

         }
```

Comment: thanks Phil, the problem is that i'm not using App Engine and for now i don't want to use it - I also tried using it like you did there but the problem is that to run this example I need to use the App Engine from Google. - but thanks.